# When you are typing a SQL Query, how to modify dropdowns

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

So, when you are typing your SQL query in SSMS, you will often be offered the little dropdown which will offer suggestions, like tables, columns, builtin functions, etc.

Is there a way to change an option so that it only shows columns?

Answer (score 0):

No.

I think you are referring to configuring Intellisense of SSMS, and as per the details on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/configure-intellisense-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017), we have limited options to configure and unfortunatly I don't see an option to restrict only columns names in the drop-down.

> **To modify Transact-SQL IntelliSense options**
>
> - On the Tools menu, click Options.
> - Expand Text Editor, expand    Transact-SQL, and then click IntelliSense.
> - Clear the check boxes for    the IntelliSense options that you do not want.
> - To change the script    size at which IntelliSense features are disabled, select a size from    the Maximum script size list.
> - To change the casing applied to    function names in completion lists, select a casing specification    from the Casing for built-in
>     function names list.
> - Click OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do as exactly as you want.

However, you can do some customized setting for the IntelliSense as the instruction below from Microsoft documentation.

**To modify Transact-SQL IntelliSense options**

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
2. Expand **Text Editor**, expand **Transact-SQL**, and then click
   **IntelliSense**.
3. Clear the check boxes for the IntelliSense options that you do not
   want.
4. To change the script size at which IntelliSense features are
   disabled, select a size from the **Maximum script size** list.
5. To change the casing applied to function names in completion lists,
   select a casing specification from the **Casing for built-in function
   names** list.
6. Click OK.